# Writing A Socket Server Application

Tags: networking

I have to design a server socket program.The requirement is Each connection from client will be in different threads.

The challenge is Suppose Server is now connected with two client Client A and client B.They will be in two different thread.

My application requirement is when server will get some message from Client A or Client B ,after processing this message it will send the messages to both Client A and client B.

Can you please suggest what will be the right approach for it .How to know what clients are open at a time .

Comment: Not trying to be rude but you might want to accept some answers on your questions. That tells people that you value their efforts by acknowledging their answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple really - have data structures shared by the two threads and protected from [concurrent access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)). You can design the sending based on a [message queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) like pattern.

Comment: Ok so you mean i will create a list insert the connected socket descriptor into the Variable .In the each connected  thread  i will process the list and will send the message .And before sending i have to acquire some locks